# How to not rotate child object in game engine?

Tags: python, game-engine, objects

I have an object whose child is controlled by mouse, and the parent object can tilt towards the same z rotation. However, when the parent object rotates, the child object rotates as well, thus keeping the same relative angle between the both objects.

I managed to fix that by adding a script to the parent object, and within the script give to the child object an opposite rotation.
Here is my script:

```
import bge

obj = bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner
child = obj.children['Turret']

rot = obj.localOrientation.to_euler()
childRot = child.localOrientation.to_euler()

dRotZ = rot.z - childRot.z
rot.z += childRot.z * 0.0175 #1 deg = pi / 180 rad
childRot.z *= 0.9825 #<=> childRot.z -= childRot.z * 0.0175
obj.worldOrientation = rot.to_matrix()
child.localOrientation = childRot.to_matrix()
```

Although this script works rather fine, it is not an obvious solution, nor a very performant one I guess, is there a simpler way of achieving this?

Comment: my object is a kind of tank, thus the child being named *Turret* ;)

Comment: Use a vertex parent.

Comment: I tried that, but does it keep the child object in the `obj.children` dict from BGE's module? acted weird anyway.